# Joomla - ignored form fields with $_POST

Tags: forms, joomla, http-post

I've been trying to create a joomla form in my view. But when I use the "apply" function and try to retrieve information from the $_POST global I lack two out of three fields. I can't for my life figure out what's wrong.

Since I get one of the fields I assume that I've created the form in a somewhat Joomla fashion.

```
<form action='<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent'); ?>' method='post' name="adminForm">
<fieldset><legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_SETTING_LEGEND'); ?></legend>
<label for=' <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_FORM_NAME'); ?>'> <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_USE'); ?>: </label>
<select name=' <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_FORM_NAME'); ?>' id=' <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_FORM_NAME'); ?>'>
<option value='0'> <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_NO')?></option>             
<?php   
if ($this->m_use_osn)
    echo "<option value='1' selected>";
else 
    echo "<option value='1'>";
?>  
<?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_YES')?></option>   
</select>       
<br /> 
<label for='<?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_URL_FORM_NAME'); ?>'> <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_URL'); ?>: </label>     
<?php
if (!empty($this->m_osn_url)) 
    echo "<input type='text' value='".$this->m_osn_url."' /><br />";
else 
    echo "<input type='text' placeholder='".JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_URL_PLACEHOLDER')."' /><br /> ";
?>  
<label for='<?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_KEY_FORM_NAME'); ?>'> <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_KEY'); ?>: </label>                 
<?php
if (!empty($this -> m_osn_key))
    echo "<input type='text' value='" . $this -> m_key . "' /><br /> ";
else
    echo "<input type='text' placeholder='".JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_KEY_PLACEHOLDER')."' /><br />";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
<input type='submit' value=' <?php echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_SUBMIT'); ?> />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

However, what a `var_dump($_POST)` gives me is this:

```
array(3) {
  ["mycomponent_use"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["task"]=>
  string(5) "apply"
  ["option"]=>
  string(14) "com_mycomponent"
}
```

So, for some reason I'm not getting any of the text input fields. I've tried to get the data through `JFactory::getApplication()->input...` as well, for some reason it ignore my `<input type='text' />`. Do I have to register these in the $_POST global in some way? Since I cannot use a regular submit button but must depend on the joomla bar I am getting a bit frustrated with getting a semi empty `$_POST`.

Comment: You have forgot to give the name of input fields in form. Please assign the distinct name for each field.

Comment: Thank you! I will hang my head in shame for a while now. Give this as answer and I'll accept it and the question can be closed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to give the name of input fields in form. Please assign the distinct name for each field.You may refer this.

[Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)